# Windows 10 GattService and SmartGattLib on Android

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10, gatt

I am trying to have Android running the example on

https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib

and write a Win10 client to act as a device to be discovered by SmartGattLib.

However, it's either my Win10 or the GattService API has a problem...  My Win10 paired with the Android device, but the SmartGattLib sample program discovered on Win10 once (which I think it's impossible).

And with my Win10 + Dell M3800, I haven't figured out how to use the GattService API to write a client to publish advertisement or something to get my SmartGattLib noticed.

What have I done wrong?  Is GattService API supposed to be able to advertise?  Is it I am wrong conceptually, that Windows 10 cannot be a Gatt client?

Thanks